# Криптоалгоритм без передачи ключа. Как найти вторые ключи α и β?

Tags: python, математика, криптография

Есть задача - Пусть абоненты А и В выбрали простое число р=23 и каждый их них независимо от другого выбрал числа a=5 и b=7 соответственно.
Пусть абонент А отправляет сообщение m=17 абоненту В.

1. Найти вторые ключи α и β.
2. Вычислить значения  m1, m2, m3, m4.

Со вторым пунктом разобрался, не понял как именно найти вторые ключи. Ползал по интернету и нашёл, что ответом являются числа 9 и 19 для α и β соответственно. Есть формулы для их нахождения -

а∙α ≡ 1(mod φ(р)), 0 < α < p-1

b∙β ≡ 1(mod φ(р)), 0 < β < p-1

Так же есть формулы для значений m1, m2, m3, m4 -

m1 ≡ m^a (mod p),  0 < m1 < p

m2 ≡ m1^b (mod p),  0 < m2 < p

m3 ≡ m2^α (mod p),  0 < m3 < p

m4 ≡ m3^β (mod p),  0 < m4 < p

Как можно реализовать нахождение ключей α и β на Python?

Ниже представлен код, который у меня получился на Python для второго пункта.

```
def find_enc_message(m, a, b, alpha, beta, p):
    m1 = pow(m, a, p)
    m2 = pow(m1, b, p)
    m3 = pow(m2, alpha, p)
    m4 = pow(m3, beta, p)
    return m4


print(find_enc_message(17, 5, 7, 9, 19, 23))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас α и β - это обратные по модулю числа [(вики)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE).

Для нахождения их в `python` есть два способа:

Для Python 3.8+

```py
y = pow(x, -1, p) # x*y = 1 (mod p)
```

Для Python 3.7 и более ранние версии

```py
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

def modinv(a, m):
    g, x, y = egcd(a, m)
    if g != 1:
        raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
    else:
        return x % m
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798654/modular-multiplicative-inverse-function-in-python)